# What is causing "An error has occurred" in review?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I was performing some reviews when I got this error:

[image: problem]

Seems to be on all review topics.

Comment: I'm also getting a similar error while trying to create a question. Even though I have a title, it says the title is missing. I've tried recreating the question a few times, but I get the same error every time (even changing the text of the title).

Comment: [I can't login for some reason too](http://i.imgur.com/ct6E3Go.png)

Comment: `the server responded with a status of 418 (I'm a teapot)`

Comment: @slhck - Short and Stout? Here is my handle, here is my spout?

Comment: I think HopelessNoob broke it with the explosive amount of edits! Although, I admit, the edits are at least substantive.

Comment: I also get this while voting and creating comments :(

Comment: I am having this problem on Superuser when i vote or make a comment. Whats interesting I have the same problem on Security.SE also but that might or might not because of the firewall I am behind

Comment: I can't upvote a comment or add a comment, or upvote an answer, but upvoting questions seems to work.

Comment: I can't up or down vote anything (questions, answers, comments). Always get an error. :/

Comment: I'm also getting errors on all types of voting and attempts at leaving comments.

Comment: @CarlB I can't log in, or post a question. It says the title and question body are missing. Superuser is broken. What do you expect do for the rest of the work day...WORK?!

Answer (score 4):

We disabled CloudFlare proxy that was causing issues and Nick's gonna investigate what broke and why in a few. In the meantime, though, review, comments, authentication, etc. should be working again.